# docker-compose is failing with assertion failed error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose` is failing with the error below...

*assertion failed [header->version <= kProjectSourceVersion]: runtime library is newer than runtime
(Library.cpp:99 init)*

Any inputs on why this is the case?

Comment: Give more details. How exactly are you running Docker Compose? This looks like some error from whatever application you're running in the container, so explain what that is. If you run the application locally (assuming you can), do you get the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The default version of docker-compose (which is v 1.x) does not seem to support Rosetta 2 by default. Try to check **Use Docker Compose V2** option in the *General preferences* tab of the Docker Desktop.

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues